# Google Places Searchbox result convert to LatLng object

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-places-api

I catch the place selected from the searchbox using the Maps JavaScript API
, thats working, and I want to convert that place to a "LatLng" or "Place" object as required for the directions api. How can I convert that?

```
  searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
    var places = searchBox.getPlaces();
    if (places.length == 0) {
      return;
    }

    // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    places.forEach(function(place) {

      if (!place.geometry) {
        console.log("Returned place contains no geometry");
        return;
      }
      var icon = {
        url: place.icon,
        size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
      };

      if (place.geometry.viewport) {
        // Only geocodes have viewport.
        bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
      } else {
        bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
      }

        //Calculate route
      var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

      function calcRoute(place) {
        var start = "New York, USA";
        var end = place.formatted_address; //****Here should be a "LatLng" of place
        var request = {
          origin: start,
          destination: end,
          travelMode: 'DRIVING'
        };

        directionsService.route(request, function(result, status) {
          if (status == 'OK') {

            console.log(result);
          }
          if (status != 'OK') {

            console.log('No route found');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `LatLng` of the place is `place.geometry.location`

```
function calcRoute(place) {
    var start = "New York, USA";
    var end = place.geometry.location; //****Here should be a "LatLng" of place
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/bnc17L40/)

Comment: Thank you! Couldn't find that information in googles documentation